# Can not use xtion pro live

Tags: ros, openni, asus-xtion-pro-live

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't use the xtion pro live with usb ID 1d27:0601 on openni_launch
but the openni sample(downloaded from openni.org) seems to work

does anyone have the same problems?

I attached messages below.

```
[ INFO] [1355377465.452116040]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1355377465.452217241]: 1. device on bus 002:03 is a PrimeSense Device (601) from PrimeSense (1d27) with serial id ''
[ INFO] [1355377465.453053444]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1355377465.555017357]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-camera-1.8.0/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-camera/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 61 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: USB interface is not supported!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50325/can-not-use-xtion-pro-live/) by [Yohei Kakiuchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/53/yohei-kakiuchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just download and install PrimeSense-Sensor-Stable-5.1.0.41-1 from [openni website.](http://openni.org/Downloads/OpenNIModules.aspx)

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yohei Kakiuchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/53/yohei-kakiuchi/) on 2012-12-13**:
Thanks Alireza, openni.launch seems to work. But there are some diffs between primesense-sensor and ps-engine. Is it occurred problem?

**Comment by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on 2012-12-14**:
ps-engine deb package which is exist in ROS repositories is especially for kinect sensor!

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-02-08**:
That link to the OpenNI website is dead.  Google found this on GitHub: https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor   Check what version of openni-sensor-primesense-bin you have, mine was already Version: 5.1.0.41-1.1+lucid2